# Is $f:\mathbb E^1\to X$ continuous?

Tags: general-topology, continuity

$f(x)=x$.

$X$ is the set of all real numbers with finite complement topology (A set is open in this space iff it's complement is finite).

Comment: Ok, I assume $X$ is just $\mathbb E ^1 = \mathbb R$ in the finite complement topology.

Comment: What is $\mathbb{E}^1$? Is it a fancy way to denote $\mathbb{R}$ with the standard topology (one-dimensional Euclidean space)?

Comment: @TomCruise I have edited the question.

Comment: @DanielFischer I am currently reading Armstrong Topology and it uses this notation. Maybe it is to denote that Euclidean norm is used to define the topology over the set of reals.

Comment: I interpret that as a "yes, it denotes $\mathbb{R}$ with the standard topology". So, the easiest may be to consider closed subsets, is $f^{-1}(C)$ closed for $C$ closed in $X$?

Comment: @DanielFischer Ok. I used the same approach i.e. to take a set open in $X$ and show it's inverse (which is the same set) is closed in $\mathbb{R}$. This shows that the function is not continuous. But this is given as a "to prove it is continuous" question in Armstrong.

Comment: But the cofinite topology is (strictly) coarser than the standard topology, so $f^{-1}(\text{open})$ is open.

Comment: @DanielFischer What do you mean by "coarser"?

Comment: Let $\tau_1,\tau_2$ be two topologies on the same set. Then $\tau_1$ is coarser than $\tau_2$ (and $\tau_2$ is finer than $\tau_1$) if and only if $\tau_1 \subset \tau_2$. If the topologies are not identical, then $\tau_1$ is strictly coarser than $\tau_2$, and $\tau_2$ strictly finer than $\tau_1$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

This follows from a general fact: If $\mathcal{O}$, $\mathcal{O}^\prime$ are two topologies on a set $X$ such that $\mathcal{O}$ is finer than $\mathcal{O}^\prime$ (*i.e.*, every set in $\mathcal{O}^\prime$ is also in $\mathcal{O}$), then the identity function $\mathrm{id}_X : x \mapsto x$ is continuous as a function from $\langle X , \mathcal{O} \rangle$ to $\langle X , \mathcal{O}^\prime \rangle$.  (In fact, the converse also holds: if the identity function $\mathrm{id}_X : x \mapsto x$ is continuous as a function from $\langle X , \mathcal{O} \rangle$ to $\langle X , \mathcal{O}^\prime \rangle$, then the topology $\mathcal{O}$ is finer than the topology $\mathcal{O}^\prime$.)

Comment: Any finite open set in $\mathbb{E}^1$ does not belong to the other topology. Also the set $(-\infty, 0]\cup[1,\infty)$ is open in finite complement topology but does not belong to the other. So I don't think there is a finer set here.

Comment: @MathewGeorge A finite open set in the standard topology is empty. and $(-\infty,0] \cup [1,\infty)$ is not open in the cofinite topology, since the complement, $(0,1)$, is not finite.

Comment: I understood my mistake. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

$f$ is continuous since $\mathbb R \setminus$ (any finite set) is open in the standard space  $\mathbb R$.

Let $F$ be a finite subset of $\mathbb R$, and let {$x_1,...,x_n$} be the increasing enumeration of $F$.  Then $f^{-1} (\mathbb R \setminus F)=(-\infty, x_1)\cup (x_1,x_2)\cup ... \cup (x_n,\infty)$ is open.

Edit: Alternatively you could just notice the closed sets in $X$ are the finite sets, which are also closed in the standard $\mathbb R$.